# Как всегда получать обновления по вебсокету

Tags: python, сокет, websocket, асинхронность, asyncio

Есть вот такого рода функция

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

async def client():
    ws = await websockets.connect('wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv')
    print("Successfully connected")
    wallets = [w.address for w in Wallet.objects.all()] # достаю список всех кошельков
    for wallet in wallets:                              # прохожусь по ним циклом и подписываюсь на обновления каждого
        await ws.send('{"op":"addr_sub", "addr":"%s"}' % wallet)
        print("Successfully subscribed to %s" % wallet)
    print("Waiting...")
    response = await ws.recv()                          # принимаю результат
    data = json.loads(response)
    pprint(data)

while True:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(client())
    loop.run_forever()
```

При запуске кода получаю только 1 обновление.

```
>запустил скрипт
>совершил бтк транзакцию    
>получил обновление
>совершаю вторую
>ничего не прилетает
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не хватает цикла вокруг метода ***ws.recv***

```
async def client():
  ws = await websockets.connect('wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv')
  print("Successfully connected")
  wallets = [w.address for w in Wallet.objects.all()] # достаю список всех кошельков
    for wallet in wallets:                              # прохожусь по ним циклом и подписываюсь на обновления каждого
      await ws.send('{"op":"addr_sub", "addr":"%s"}' % wallet)
      print("Successfully subscribed to %s" % wallet)
  print("Waiting...")
  while True:
    response = await ws.recv() # если я верно понял какую либу вы используете тут 
                               # может возникнуть исключение(в зависимости от версии)
    if response == None:
      break
    else
      data = json.loads(response)
      print(data)
```